# How can I edit the colors for a specific part of an image?

Tags: photo-editing, color

I'm trying to change the color of a flower pot in a picture, as well as the leaves in the picture. I'm working with paint.net (but am open to any other free programs). Here's a little bit of the picture: [image: 1/8th the photo]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are tutorials on YouTube about [changing colors in photos](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=photo%20change%20color). Most demonstrate the techniques with Photoshop, but most image editors that support layers can be used. Generally, the methods involve creating new layers and layer masks, along with:

- Changing the **blending mode** to **color, overlay,** or **soft light.**
- Changing the **hue.**

Here are my results using GIMP. Adjusted levels first. Then changed hue for the blue pot, and used overlay blending for the green pot.

[image: color change example]